# Is there any way to use host compiler's front end & target compiler's backend in GCC?

Tags: gcc, c++11, llvm, cross-compiling, llvm-gcc

I have a host **compiler(X86_64) GCC 4.6.3 & Target compiler(MIPS) GCC 4.5.3**,

**Is there a way to use the host compiler's front-end along with target compiler's back-end**?

My question may be a bit weird, but reason for asking this is to use the latest **C++11 standards while coding for embedded platforms where the target compiler still lags to support** these features.

(I'm assuming all these C++11 features are implemented in compiler front-end & nothing related to CPU specific back-end)

Also is it possible to use LLVM + GCC combination for this requirement?

(Any suggestions/tips appreciated!!)

**EDIT:** (Added possible options known to me!)

1. Getting the latest toolchain from chip vendtor (Time consuming)
2. Building my own toolchain from GCC source (3rd party library compatibility issues)

Comment: Get GCC 4.6.3 for MIPS?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, it is somewhat difficult and time consuming to get it from the chip vendor.

Comment: You're assuming wrong, an awful lot of C++11 features are part of the standard library (in your case, `libstdc++` 4.5.3, you see the problem...). As a side note, GCC 4.6.3 is far from offering "the latest C++11 standards", GCC 4.8.1 is feature complete as far as the core language is concerned but far from complete on the standard library side.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to build your toolchain yourself, provided your target platform is not too exotic (read: doesn't require patches to the compiler). I for one had to resort to that because I couldn't get my hands on a pre-built GCC 4.8 cross-compiler for ARM.

Comment: @syam I initially thought of compiling my own, but I'm afraid of vendor specific patches :(

Answer (score 3):

No. There are two reasons:

- The assumption does not hold. C++11 features are spread across the frontend, the backend and the standard C++ library. A few features might be possible in front-end only without the other parts, but most of them not.
- GCC policy is to keep the front-end and back-end linked together. It has no technical reason, it's purely political. But it prevents exchanging the front-end.

Comment: @"Jan Hudec", You mean both F-E & B-E are not compatible across different versions of GCC?

Comment: He means that there is no "frontend" and "backend". GCC is one monolithical piece, not modular.

Comment: It can be impressive what you can do. I was able to use C++11 variadic templates (I "compile-runned" my compile-time turing machine simulator) with my GCC backend without doing anything specific about C++ support (my goal was to support C, which I succeeded in). All the things that pop up my mind, like decltype, variadic templates, auto, initializer lists don't look as if they would require backend support.